# Create USDT Wallet on ERC20 Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, web3dart

I want to understand for myself how to generate USDT ERC20 wallet in dart language. I found the [web3dart](https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart) library. But what does it take to generate a koschel using the 12-word phrase provided by the [bip39](https://pub.dev/packages/bip39) library? And I don’t understand, is it necessary to write a smart contract? I would like to see a small code example of how to generate a wallet. Many thanks.

### Update:

I seem to have managed to generate a wallet. But how to make exactly USDT on ERC20?

```
var random = Random.secure();
var mnemonic = 'obvious width mechanic wheat cargo toe bike seek spirit jungle enlist thumb';
String mnemonicToSeedHex = bip39.mnemonicToSeedHex(mnemonic);
EthPrivateKey credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(mnemonicToSeedHex);
Wallet wallet = Wallet.createNew(credentials, mnemonic, random);
var address = await credentials.extractAddress();
dev.log(address.hex);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since USDT is an erc-20 token, you can use the erc-20 abi for contract interactions.

```
final _erc20ContractAbi = web3.ContractAbi.fromJson(
        '[{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]',
        'Erc20');
```

Now write a class to interact with each functions in the abi. You need to pass the contract address, web3client (infura or any other) and chainID (1 for ethereum mainnet)

```
class ERC20 extends web3.GeneratedContract {
  ERC20({
    required web3.EthereumAddress address,
    required web3.Web3Client client,
    int? chainId,
  }) : super(web3.DeployedContract(_erc20ContractAbi, address), client,
            chainId);
```

Now you can get the balance of your USDT by writing a balanceOf method inside the class like this,

```
Future<BigInt> balanceOf(
    web3.EthereumAddress account, {
    web3.BlockNum? atBlock,
  }) async {
    final function = self.abi.functions[2];
    assert(checkSignature(function, '70a08231'));
    final params = [account];
    final response = await read(function, params, atBlock);
    return (response[0] as BigInt);
  }
```

Function to Transafer USDT tokens,

```
Future<String> transfer(
    web3.EthereumAddress recipient,
    BigInt amount, {
    required web3.Credentials credentials,
    web3.Transaction? transaction,
  }) async {
    final function = self.abi.functions[7];
    assert(checkSignature(function, 'a9059cbb'));
    final params = [recipient, amount];
    return write(credentials, transaction, function, params);
  }
```

Check out my article on Medium , [Crypto-wallet app using flutter](https://medium.com/p/9f67b0d0819f) to get an idea on how to build your own erc-20 token and use flutter mobile application to build a wallet that can transfer the coins.

Comment: Bro, thanks, you're awesome. Where are you getting these values?
'70a08231' and 'a9059cbb'?

Comment: Thank you brother. Those values are ERC-20 function signatures.

totalSupply() - 18160ddd

balanceOf(address) - 70a08231

allowance(address,address) - dd62ed3e

transfer(address,uint256) - a9059cbb

approve(address,uint256) - 095ea7b3

transferFrom(address,address,uint256) - 23b872dd

You can get full list just by googling.

Comment: Hello @ArunXena great articles i read them all, thank you for breaking them down into fine details, may the uinverse grant you grace.